# Apache File does not exist but all links work

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have thousands of "File does not exist" in the apache error logs. The strange thing is that the referer is my website and when you view the source code there is no URL request for /images.

What could be causing this?

```
[Sun Aug 28 03:15:31 2011] [error] [client 2.219.154.210] File does not exist: /var/www/oneclickrecruitment/public/jobs, referer: http://www.oneclickrecruitment.co.uk/jobs/construction-and-skilled-trades/electricians-and-part-qualified-electricians/
[Sun Aug 28 04:06:28 2011] [error] [client 207.46.12.121] File does not exist: /var/www/oneclickrecruitment/public/images, referer: http://www.oneclickrecruitment.co.uk/employers
```

The big problem here is that I have fail2ban setup with apache-noscript which means that innocent users are getting blocked for just viewing the website.

EDIT: I am still getting the above errors for every visit. Thus the reason for the bounty for helping me solve this problem please.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName oneclickrecruitment.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.oneclickrecruitment.co.uk www.oneclickrecruitment.com www.1clickrecruitment.co.uk www.1clickrecruitment.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/oneclickrecruitment/public

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/oneclickrecruitment-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/oneclickrecruitment-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# Redirect for non existent subdomains
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.oneclickrecruitment.co.uk *.oneclickrecruitment.com *.1clickrecruitment.co.uk *.1clickrecruitment.com
    Redirect 301 / http://www.oneclickrecruitment.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What is the question here? If the files/folders don't exist you'll get these messages. Do they exist or not?

Comment: +1 on incomplete question, you need to give a bit more detail, do the directories exist? What are the links/redirects in your referrer to those directories?

Comment: Does `/var/www/oneclickrecruitment/public/images` exist?

Comment: Sorry, no the files do not exist at: http://www.oneclickrecruitment.co.uk/images

Comment: Can anybody help with this? No the files/folders do not exist. BUT why is the referer a page on my site also?

Comment: @John If you docroot is `/var/www/oneclickrecruitment/public/`, then `/var/www/oneclickrecruitment/public/jobs` ought to exist when the referrer is a page under `/jobs` - but you said the directories don't exist?  Can you post your Apache config, and clarify what the directory structure looks like?

Comment: I have added the vhost for the domain I am having the problems with thanks

Comment: can you give us the output of `ls -l /var/www/oneclickrecruitment/public`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking through some of your pages and came across a 404 that might be relevant.

It is in your HTML Header:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/webapp/templates/default/images/apple-icon.png" />
```

I wonder if that is what is mapping to `/var/www/oneclickrecruitment/public/images`

I looked at the first page for the `.../public/jobs` error and I didn't see any errors for media in that directory.  I'll try to keep looking for it.

Comment: Did that fix both of the problems? or is the other one still outstanding?

Comment: Sadly not no and didn't even solved the error messages. Thanks tho

Answer (score 2):

You have two broken image links in your site code (for the urls you have given in the question) which are,

http://www.oneclickrecruitment.co.uk/webapp/templates/default/images/application_links.jpg

http://www.oneclickrecruitment.co.uk/webapp/templates/default/images/input.png

Could you correct these and check whether the issue still persist.

Comment: That seems to have solved it. Thank you so much. How did you find these missing images? I looked on the firebug net status and everything returned OK.

Comment: I always use http://tools.pingdom.com/ . Have a great day!

Comment: Sadly this problem has turned, I also get the error:[Thu Sep 01 23:07:57 2011] [error] [client 109.158.215.129] File does not exist: /var/www/oneclickrecruitment/public/jobs, referer: http://www.oneclickrecruitment.co.uk/jobs/construction-and-skilled-trades/electricians-and-part-qualified-electricians/

Answer (score 0):

Relative include for a resource? ie: "../images"